# How to use plugin globalization in ionic3 and angular5

Tags: ionic3

I want to get my device language and translate content by device language.

I reference https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/globalization/ And trying to use it.

this is my app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClient,HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization'

export function createTranslateLoader(http:HttpClient){
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/','.json')
}
   . . .
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory:(createTranslateLoader),
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
  })
  ],
  providers: [
    Globalization
  ]
```

this is my app.component.ts

```
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization'
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(public Translate:TranslateService,private global: Globalization) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.Translate.setDefaultLang('EN');
    this.global.getPreferredLanguage()
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
  }
}
```

this is my home.html

```
 <ion-title> {{'HOME.TITLE'  | translate}} </ion-title>
 <h2>  {{'HOME.CONTENT' |  translate}}</h2>
```

This is my Package.json

```
{"@angular/core": "5.2.11"
 "@angular/http": "5.2.11"
"@ionic-native/globalization": "^4.20.0"
"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1"
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0"
"cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0"
"description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {}
    }
  }
```

It only shows the default language(EN),i want it to translate other languages with the device language by my chose.please tell me how can i solve it or provide me some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are referring **Ionic V4** Doc instead of that Refer **Ionic V3**
>   Doc

[V3 DOC](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/globalization/)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization
npm install --save @ionic-native/globalization@4
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/ng2-translate/

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

Comment: "@ionic-native/globalization": "^5.10.0" install 4

Comment: Now i Reinstalled “@ ionic-native / globalization” to 4.20, the language displayed by my app is obtained using setDefaultLang('EN'), but i want it to translate other languages with the device language by my chose.

Comment: I guess the reason is that ,I didn't do anything to make the plugin work, so the plugin seems not work.

Comment: This plugin is used for getting information about users’ locale language, date and time zone, currency, etc. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_globalisation.htm

Comment: do you want to change app language?

Comment: Yes.i want My app language is according to the user's device language

Comment: first you get app language using this plugin then `ngx-translate ` https://enappd.com/blog/how-to-translate-in-ionic-4-globalization-internationalization-and-localization/11/

Comment: Thanks you,I need to take some time to understand and implement it.